# Changing a column name in lazy table

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am working on some project. I have a table called `emp_hierarchy`.
It has two columns `emp_id`, `salary`.

When I check the class of it, `class(emp_hierarchy)`, it is showing something like below.

> "tbl_impala" "tbl_sql"    "tbl_lazy"   "tbl"

I want to change the name of `emp_id` column as `associate_id`.

Can you please help me in solving it?

```
colnames(emp_hierarchy)[which(names(emp_hierarchy) == "emo_id")] <- "associate_id"
```

> error : Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 'dimnames' applied to non-array

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput(head(df,n))`. Also add current and expected output. Your question as is is hard to find a solution to.

Comment: Maybe `names(dimnames(emp_hierarchy)) <- c("associate_id", "salary")`

Comment: hi NelseonGon, Matt  -  I found an answer and posted it. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer :)

```
 rename(
   associate_id = emp_id
 )
```